# Is it possible to create an instance of Windows that has the limited amount of files needed to run?

Tags: windows, windows-7, virtualbox, windows-registry

I have been experimenting with virtual machines and I am trying to figure out if their is a way to create a limited instance of Windows from your own version you are running?

An example would be that you are running Windows 7 and you would like to create another instance that has just the limited amount of files and registry it needs to run. So basically an empty instance of Windows created from the host system that can be ran in a guest system in a Virtual Machine.

I know most of you would just say why not install a new copy of Windows in it but I am creating an application that uses a VM and needs to run an instance of Windows, although due to licensing I wouldn't be able to include a copy of Windows in the application.

Is there any software that can create an instance from your own that can be recommended? I know that their is a few that allow you to make full clones of the operating system and it adds it to a Virtual Image to run in a VM but the only issue with that is it copies the whole system and not just necessary windows files so the images are way to big and it wouldn't be feasible.

I am thinking maybe an alternative is to grab a fresh copy of each OS and creating a script to map out the file system and registry and copy all files. So I know which ones it needs to run.

---

**EDIT:**

Well after some more research I found software to create live CDs with the bare minimum and that it is actually very easy. This is exactly what I need. Although so far I have seen you need to create them from the Windows install disc so does anyone know about creating them without it and using the file system/registry?

Comment: I think you'd get into "am I sure I got **everything** issues. How can you test you have everything you need?

Comment: Well after some more research I found software to create live Cds with the bare minimum. This is exactly what I need. Although so far I have seen you need to create them from the windows install disc.

Comment: The reason you're required to create them from the installation disc is that once Windows is installed the selected [HAL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99588) and hardware-specific drivers would most likely caused BSODs if you attempt to load the image on dissimilar physical or virtual hardware. You might be able to image, use SysPrep and get rid of non-essential files, but I'm not sure if it'll work. Time to experiment!

Comment: There's a stripped down version of Windows 7 that removes all the components that aren't essential, and can be run without a serial number. It's called Tiny7 and can be downloaded from The Pirate Bay. Your government might have blocked the website because it's a piracy or warez website.

Comment: You can download the official Microsoft Windows 7 iso files here. Someone made a backup of the files. https://digitalrivermirror.com/ Microsoft removed the download links from their website to put it behind a serial number requirement whilst no longer allowing you to buy a serial number, to prioritise Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

The minimal Windows is called [Windows PE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Preinstallation_Environment) which is what you see while installing Windows or running Windows Recovery. It's also used in 3<sup>rd</sup> party Windows-based  rescue disks. Each major Windows version will have a corresponding Windows PE

> Windows PE (WinPE) for Windows 10 is a small operating system used to install, deploy, and repair Windows 10 for desktop editions (Home, Pro, Enterprise, and Education), Windows Server, and other Windows operating systems. From Windows PE, you can:
>
> - Set up your hard drive before installing Windows.
> - Install Windows by using apps or scripts from a network or a local drive.
> - Capture and apply Windows images.
> - Modify the Windows operating system while it's not running.
> - Set up automatic recovery tools.
> - Recover data from unbootable devices.
> - Add your own custom shell or GUI to automate these kinds of tasks.
>
> https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-intro

To create a Windows PE disk you need Windows ADK which is provided for free by Microsoft. For more details read [Create bootable WinPE media](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/winpe-create-usb-bootable-drive)